# PHP include code for if file exists and what to do if it doesn't

Tags: php, file-io, include, require

Long ago, this code used to work but now it seems something is going on preventing it from functioning properly. I'm hoping somebody can tell me whats going on. I'm concerned upgrades to PHP have killed this code. Or has it?

I use this code (posted below) to check and to see if an html file exists, and if it does it'll use it. If not, it will use the file index2.html.

```
<?php if ((file_exists("$id.html")) == true) { require ("$id.html"); } else { require ("index2.html"); } ?>
```

I use this code on my homepage, index.php. However for some odd reason, when I type in a link: example: index.php?id=exampleurlhere, the code isn't checking to see if the file exists and is automatically using the index2.html file, despite my code telling that if the file exists (which it does), then it's required to use it. Why is it now ignoring my command?

Been using this code for years and never had any problems with it until recently it seems. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: is this only the code you're using? is `$_GET['id']` assigned to `$id`?

Comment: Try `if(file_exists("$id.html") == true)` instead of `if ((file_exists("$id.html")) == true)` - Sometimes, extra brackets can play dirty tricks.

Comment: However, this `require ("$id.html")` - what's inside that `.html` file? Requires are usually related to classes/functions, etc.

Comment: Sadly there was no change. To answer your question, inside those html files are pictures and text. No there is no $_GET code, and there never was one, even when it was working. Perhaps this is something that's changed?

Comment: So, how is `$id` being defined?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not a coder. So I'm not sure what you mean when how $id is being defined. If I use plain ol' url.com/index.php, the include would pull from index2.html (this part still works, btw). If I used url.com/index.php?id=pagehere, it would pull pagehere.html (this is the portion not working anymore).

Comment: Hopefully, `$id` isn't provided by the user. If that is the case, you are vulnerable to directory traversal attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the "register_globals" setting. This used to be on by default in the (very) older versions of PHP, but has been removed in the newer versions, as this caused a lot of variable injection attacks in the old PHP.

Your $id came directly from the value in the URL. Now that it no longer auto registers, you can add in a line "$id=$_GET['id'];" just above that line to get it to work again.

This is just a quick fix. I suggest you rewrite the program so that there will not be any change of users accessing files illegally using the URL.

Comment: Thank you. That code did the trick. I'm not a php coder, I just happened to run across that code years agi and have been using it ever since. So I wouldn't have the slightest clue how to rewrite that code to make it safer. But I see your point about it not being safe so they shut it down. Thanks again for your information.